# Has any significant political group in the US opposed eminent domain in all circumstances?

Tags: united-states, eminent-domain

Has there ever been any significant political group (more than a very small number of people, not necessarily a group with a large amount of influence, e.g. a minor political party counts, but a few people upset over their friend's land being taken does not) which opposed eminent domain in all circumstances, no matter how great the benefit to the public? For example, such a group would believe that given the choice between a ten-mile straight road with part of a farm being taken by eminent domain and a fifty-mile road going around the farm, the fifty-mile road is the only acceptable option.

Do any such groups currently exist?

Comment: Libertarians maybe? (according to what they say, not what they do)

Comment: If the Libertarian Party can be counted a significant political grouping, they seem to oppose it, although it's not clear if this is a [general statement against it](https://www.lp.org/platform/) or something that absolutely applies in all circumstances. Maybe someone could research in more detail, although it's hard to judge how a party will act when in power based on general statements of principles.

Comment: Could you give a short explanation of 'eminent domain'?

Comment: @Ivana 'Eminent domain' is the right a government gives itself or its agents to take private property away from the owner for public use, with payment of compensation. We wouldn't have nice straight roads, nice straight railroads, huge military bases, etc. were it not for that governmental right to take private property (with compensation).

Comment: @StuartF You should make that an answer, with the caveat that the Libertarian Party might or might not be considered a "significant political group."

Comment: @DavidHammen I would consider them a significant political group. I should have clarified that; I just meant "not three people getting together and complaining about eminent domain." I'll edit the question.

Comment: What would you consider a significant political group? Knowing this is critical to answering your question. When you are talking about a country of 300 million plus saying a "small number of people" needs some clarifying. In this country a group can have a large number of people and not much influence or a small number and strong influence depending on who they are.

Comment: @JoeW I would consider a group significant if they are more than just a local group and at least make efforts to influence politics. Basically, they're significant if there is any chance that they might actually make a difference without growing significantly first. I might even just remove the word; I just wanted to exclude cases where (for example) someone's land is taken away and they get a few friends upset over it.

Comment: That is information that should be edited into your question.

Comment: Eminent domain is sometimes used to allow military bases. But it is also sometimes allowed to create shopping malls. There is some political thought that there are acceptable and unacceptable uses of ED.

Comment: @BobaFit yes, I am aware of that. Most people except shopping mall developers would oppose using it to build a mall. I'm asking whether there are people who would oppose it in all cases, even if it would have very significant benefits to the public.

Answer (score 4):

From the current [Libertarian party platform](https://www.lp.org/platform/):

> we oppose all government interference with private property, such as confiscation, nationalization, and **eminent domain**

Comment: This answer could be improved by demonstrating the significance of the Libertarian party. Citing current enrollment numbers should be fine.